# Are there contextual link styles for list-group-items?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3.2.0, are there contextual link styles to match `list-group-item`s such as `list-group-item-danger`? Right now I'm just using the `text-danger` class on the link but I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: No, you have to stick with `text-danger`. Of if you use LESS you can extend your own version of `list-group-item-danger`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I am probably going to make my own styles for it then. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just use `text-danger`?

Comment: I can, but I'm building something where there will be a lot of cases where I need this (generated by php but still)

Comment: You looking for http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-contextual-classes ?

Comment: @cvrebert That is what I'm using. I wanted to know if there was an accompanying class to style the links to match.